# How to display/communicate "bulk" pricing on a b2b ecommerce marketplace

Tags: e-commerce

I have a b2b ecommerce marketplace (multi-vendor, like amazon).

I'm looking for some inspirations/examples of how other b2b marketplace are communication things like bulk pricing.

As an example, in our case, you can buy a solar panel but the piece, the pallet, or the container.

Some similar discussions:

[Ecommerce B2B vs B2C product display](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98726/ecommerce-b2b-vs-b2c-product-display)

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous options:

1. consider all these as different product, with different prizes
2. consider them as a single product, but then, when it comes to prizing, you might get things more complex.

Keep in mind that this is a B2B scenario, where the single piece won't make much sense. In case of the 2nd option you would need to have a price range on the product - that might vary based on amount, user's VIP status, etc.

Comment: Thanks. In our case, technically/data-wise we will treat them as separate products with separate SKU. The UI gets more complicated when you consider it's also a multi-vendor marketplace so you have multiple prices/vendors for the single, pallet, and container options.